# Creating orderer node in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and am starting a new project which is to transfer asset from one person to another.  Here are the steps which I think I need to follow to achieve the completion of the project, do tell me if I am wrong or I missed something:

1. Create an orderer node.
2. Create a channel.
3. Create peers and endorser nodes.
4. Connect each peer and endorser node to channel.
5. Write chaincode and endorsing policies.
6. Create transaction to update ledger state.

If I am right, can someone help me with creation of orderer node, or provide me a link which helps. Also wanted to ask that orderer node creation is possible using node SDK.

Answer (score 2):

In Hyperledger Fabric there are 3 types of nodes. Each node is a process running on some machine (perhaps in a container) and communicates with other nodes in the network.

The nodes are:
- Orderer node
- Peer node
- Client node that embeds a client SDK in some language/framework (node.js, golang, java).

You can't create a node on its own. Each node, is correlated with some organization and has its own certificates and private key.

You can take a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/ (read the https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html to understand how) and this would allow you to grasp better the core concepts.

After that when you'll be more certain and more knowledgeable, you could also try to deploy your own setup of Fabric on multiple machines.
You can take a look at https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment to how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to deploying Hyperledger Fabric... the operational aspects (deploying the containers that run the orderer, peer, ca, etc runtime components) and the transactional aspects (creating channels and issuing transaction proposals etc).

Suggest that you look into the [tutorials](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) provided. Specifically, I would start with ["building your first network"](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html). This example gets into the details of how to deploy the network, create a channel and issue transactions.